# Visualize Activity Back Stack and Fragment Back Stack in Android Profiling IN Android Stdio

Tags: android-studio, back-stack, android-profiler

All I can see is the current activity in the profiler, I feel like there should be a way to visualize the whole back stack of activities as well as fragments.
How much of this is possible, please let me know how to, if you have done this.